# add class active on li tag after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu that has the route like this:

(about / services / basic services)

I want when I click on "basic services" after the page refresh the active `li` goes on "basic services" `li` tag, and other tags removed from `active` class. How can I do it?

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
       <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
       <li><span>About</span>
           <ul>
               <li><span>Services</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./index.html">basic sevices</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is this a true page reload, or is this a spa transition thing?

Comment: this is a true page reload . @Taplar

Comment: Ok then, my first thought is you could interogate the window.location.href to see if it ends with 'index.html' and if so do whatever logic you want.  There may be other options.  EDIT: or you could try to do a find for an element that you know only exists on the index page and base it off of that.

Comment: can you see this plz? https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index.html
i want some thing like this , that after clicking on menu item and refresh site the active class goes on menu that are in href. @Taplar

Comment: If i view source on that page, active is already on the link clicked.  Which says that it is being done on the backend, not with frontend javascript, contrary to what you are asking for.

Comment: is there any way that shows me to do this eith javascript? 

i use this but it is not working :
 console.log(window.location.href);
    if ($("li").children('a').attr("href") == window.location.href){}

Comment: Console log your window.location.href, which you are doing, and also the href that you are comparing to it to see how they relate.  Also reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: can you see this :

$(window).load(function() {

    if ($("li").click(function() {
            console.log(window.location.href);
            if ($(this).children("a").attr("href") == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass("mm-selected");
            };
        }));

and in console.log it immidatly shows and disappear after page refresh.
where am i wrong?
@Taplar

Comment: You should set the class when the page loads not when the link is clicked. When a new page is loaded, the browser doesn't remember the class you just added.